# What is the inverse Fourier transform for abstract measure ？

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

> We kown that, for Lebesgue Measure, the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ of $f$ is defined by
>   $$
> \hat{f}(\xi)=\int f(x)e^{-i\pi \xi x}dx 
> $$
>   for all $\xi\in \Bbb R$, and the inverse Fourier transform is
>   $$
> f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int \hat{f}(\xi)e^{-i\pi \xi x}d\xi
> $$
>   for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Let $\mu$ be a finite, compactly supported Borel measure on $\Bbb R^n$. The Fourier transform of $f$ is defined by
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)=\int f(x)e^{-2\pi i \xi\cdot x}d\mu(x) \quad(\xi\in\Bbb R^n).
$$
What is the inverse Fourier transform for abstract measure $\mu$, and why ？

Comment: If $\mu$ is a finite and absolutely continuous measure then $d\mu(x) = h(x)dx $ for some $h \in L^1$ which means $\hat{\mu}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2i \pi \xi x} d\mu(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2i \pi \xi x} h(x)dx = \mathcal{F}[h](\xi)$ and  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2i \pi \xi x} f(x) d\mu(x) = \mathcal{F}[f h](\xi)$. In general $d\mu(x) = H'(x)dx$ for some function $H$ so that $\hat{\mu}(\xi) = 2i \pi \xi \mathcal{F}[H](\xi)$ and $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty  f(x) d\mu(x)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty  f(x) \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\hat{\mu}](x)dx$ (this leads to the distribution theory)

Comment: Does this mean that $f(x)=\int \hat{f}(\xi)e^{-2\pi i \xi\cdot x}d\mu(\xi) \quad(x\in\Bbb R^n)$？

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2287149/8157)