# Fourier transform of a bounded function over a finite measure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, fourier-analysis, conditional-probability

So I have been trying to apply Fourier transform to a particular setting/problem in probability theory. I am dealing with equations that do have logarithm of sigmoidal function or linear transformations of sigmoidal functions, where sigmoidal function is $\sigma(x):=(1+\exp(-x))$, and my functions are of the form $h_{\alpha}(x)\log(\alpha\sigma(x)+(1-\alpha))$ where these functions model conditional distribution of $p(y|x)$ where $y$ is a binary random variable.

As it stands since $h_{\alpha}(x)\not\in L_1$ it is not possible to conclude that Fourier transform of $h_{\alpha}(x)$ exists. On the other hand taking a density like Normal density would imply $h_{\alpha}(x)p(x)\in L_1$ which is just the expectation of conditional log-likelihood over $y=1$ examples, i.e. $\mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[\log(p(y=1|X)]$ which I presume(?), would enable me to apply Fourier transform on them.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Definition) refers to a claim that Fourier transform for a bounded function over a finite measure exist:

> "By contrast, the characteristic function or Fourier transform always exists (**because it is the integral of a bounded function on a space of finite measure**), and for some purposes may be used instead."

-- First question is that is this claim true and if so could you please refer me to a reference that proves this?

-- Second question is that in more general case where I have $h_{\alpha}(x)p(x)\in L_1$ can I use Fourier transform and then absorb $p(x)$ into $dx$ to convert Lebesgue measure to the measure of $p(x)$ and define my Fourier transform this way to make sure its existence?

Comment: I am not sure what you're looking for with 1?  The function $x \mapsto e^{itx}$ is obviously bounded for any $t$, and it's obvious that bounded functions are in $L_1(\mu)$ when $\mu$ is finite.

Comment: For the second question, the Fourier transform of $h_\alpha(x)$ with respect to the measure $p(x)dx$ is exactly the same as the Fourier transform of $h_\alpha(x) p(x)$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $dx$.  This is immediate from the definitions, and neither gains nor loses you anything.

Comment: @NateEldredge my first question is about that claim in general: that a bounded function on a space of finite measure has always have Fourier transform.

Comment: @NateEldredge for the second one. The difference is that even if h_a(x) might not be in $L_1$, $h_a(x)p(x)$ might be. So by right choice of $p(x)$ one can make sure the Fourier transform exist and that was my exact question.

Comment: For the first one, let $h(x)$ be a bounded function by some constant $u$. Then we have that $\displaystyle \left|  \int_{\Omega} h(x) e^{-itx} \mu(dx) \right| \leq \int_{\Omega}  \left|  h(x) e^{-itx} \right| \mu(dx) \leq  \int_{\Omega} u \mu(dx) \leq u \mu(\Omega) < + \infty$. The last step follows from finiteness of the measure \mu. Thus, the Fourier transform exists.

Comment: For the second one, even if $\displaystyle \int h_a(x) p(x) e^{-itx} dx $ exists, I am not getting how can you relate it to $\displaystyle \int h_a(x) e^{-itx} dx $, the Fourier transform of $h_a(x)$, and obtain information about the same. I guess @NateEldredge was asking the same thing.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Thanks for the answer. I wonder if there is reference that I could read about the Fourier transform over arbitrary measures. I haven't found a single reference!  Also I am not sure if the inequalities are always true, especially the left-most one and the second left-most one. Sorry I am not well-versed in calculus and especially complex calculus.

Comment: @sudeep5221, for the second one, it really does not matter. I am working on a proof that works in frequency domain, so the moment that I have existence of them I can continue my proof in the frequency domain. Although I would be interested to know if the inverse exist. Somebody asked this question already but there is no definitive answer for it there:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444242/what-is-the-inverse-fourier-transform-for-abstract-measure

Comment: @Cupitor I am pretty certain that the proof for the first one is correct. I don't know about if any book that has Fourier Analysis over arbitrary measures. I had referred to Fourier Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi when I read about it in a course. That book has it over Lebesgue measure only iirc, but is a good starting point. Also a lot properties carry over to general measures.

Comment: @Cupitor For the second one, yes if $h(x)p(x) \in L_1$ then you can use the property above to conclude that its Fourier transform exists. However, it will be the Fourier transform of $h(x)$ with a different measure given by your probability measure and not Lebesgue measure. If that helps you in your problem then yes certainly you can use it. And yes you can do that "absorption" technique. That is essentially using the Radon Nikodym derivative.

Comment: @sudeep5221 thanks so much for the replies. I just want to educated myself. I guess things that change are for example change of variable in Fourier transform. For example with Lebesgue-based one the formula is available as $\mathcal{F}(f(ax))(\nu)=1/|a|\mathcal{F}(f(x))(\nu/a)$. But I tried to prove a similar thing for a different measure (took it to be Gaussian) and couldn't really. I guess that's why I am asking for a reference.

Comment: @sudeep5221 I guess things go well initially but as I pointed out in my previous comment the change of variable is not as smooth as it used to be. I think I will rather assume a compact support for my function and then apply just the normal fourier transform.